# postgres optimization with not null

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization

I have an index on one of my table such as

```
CREATE INDEX myindex
  ON mytable
  USING btree
  (myfield1, myfield2, myfield3 DESC NULLS LAST, myfield4 DESC, myfield5)
  WHERE myfield6 IS NOT NULL;
```

I m trying to optimize a request

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM "mytable" 
WHERE (myfield1 = 9 
   AND myfield5<164 
  AND myfield2 <= 40.0 
  AND (myfield6 IS NOT NULL))

=> count: 7116

Aggregate  (cost=10780.84..10780.85 rows=1 width=0)
  ->  Index Scan using myindex on mytable  (cost=0.42..10751.64 rows=11683 width=0) 
        Index Cond: ((myfield1 = 9) AND (myfield2 <= 40::double precision) AND (myfield5 < 164))
```

and by testing, I found out that replacing "myfield2 <= 40.0" by "myfield2 is not null AND myfield2 <= 40.0" gives the same results, use the same index, but the cost is half of the previous request

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM "mytable" 
WHERE (myfield1 = 9 
   AND myfield5<164 
   AND myfield2 is not null 
   AND myfield2 <= 40.0 
   AND (myfield6 IS NOT NULL))
=> count: 7116

Aggregate  (cost=4467.24..4467.25 rows=1 width=0)
  ->  Index Scan using myindex on mytable  (cost=0.42..4455.91 rows=4533 width=0)
        Index Cond: ((myfield1 = 9) AND (myfield2 IS NOT NULL) AND (myfield2 <= 40::double precision) AND (myfield5 < 164))
```

I can't understand why the cost is much less?

Comment: 1) Did you run the second query *after* the first one ? 2) did you run vacuum analyze after creating the index? 3) how large is the table? 4) always use `explain analyze` instead of only `explain`.

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL's artificial intelligence is also not high enough to know that all rows that satisfy

```
myfield1 = 9 AND myfield5 < 164 AND myfield2 <= 40.0 AND myfield6 IS NOT NULL
```

must necessarily satisfy

```
myfield2 IS NOT NULL
```

There is always a trade-off here – smarter planner means longer planning time, and it is a bad bet to punish everyone for a benefit that can be only reaped by a “bad” query.

These conditions will be treated as independent.

Based on your numbers I'd guess that `myfield2 IS NULL` in more than half of the rows.

Comment: +1 because the queries are not the same. One cannot automatically assume `myfield2 NOT NULL`, the other is given this information explicitly.